Github GraphQL API to get codeScanning alerts
Is there a GraphQL equivalence in github API for the REST /repos/:owner/:repo/code-scanning/alerts endpoint?
I don't see anything in the doc, tried vulnerabilityAlerts, for example
query {
  repository(owner: "owner", name: "repo") {
    vulnerabilityAlerts(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        createdAt
        dismissedAt
        id
      }
    }
  }
}

But the nodes returned are empty.
